# How to determine bottleneck in page load time?

Tags: dns, page-load-time

I have created a one page static website with the text "Hello". When I open the page using other third party websites, they report load times of around 15ms. When I open the website from my location, it takes between 500ms - 2s to load.

I'm trying to determine if this is a problem with my ISP, congestion, the DNS Servers in my area, or settings on the computers I am using to open this website. My internet connection is 4Mbps, so it should be able to open a small page like this quickly.

How can I diagnose why the same website takes 15ms somewhere else in the world, but 500ms in my office ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a plugin or if you have Chrome, use its built-in inspector.

Google Chrome:
Right-click on anything and click "Inspect element" and click "Network" tab on the new box that appears. Navigate to your site, you will now see in real-time how the browser is receiving the information helping you pinpoint what is slowing it down.

You can also use something called "PageSpeed" https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli?hl=en which can give suggestions as to what you can do to improve responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

What you don't say is how far the hosting is from your location

Latency rather than bandwidth is the key factor affecting download performance, and the latency to you office is likely to be higher than testing tools on the web that are hosted in data centres

What I'd do is test the page from multiple locations using webpagetest.org - this will give you some idea of the variation around the world